# Regex for 8 digit phone number (Singapore number length)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to validate my phone address text field. Can anyone provide me a simple regex to either validate for numeric digits only or a specific 8 digit regex?

Much thanks!

```
$('#phone').on('input', function() {
var input = $( this );
var regex = /* regex needed here */
var is_phone = regex.test(input.val());
if (is_phone){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
else {input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
});
```

Comment: There are literally thousands of examples out there. The pattern is simple: `^\d{8}$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will allow 0-9 numbers and only 8 digits. Try this:

```
var regex = '/^[0-9]{1,8}$/'; // if you want min 1 and max 8 numbers

var regex = '/^[0-9]{8}$/'; // if you want exact 8 numbers
```

Comment: The OP is not very clear, but I believe the number should have exactly 8 numbers,  not between 1 and 8.

Comment: in that case var regex = '/^[0-9]{8}$/';

Comment: Absolutely great answer. Apostrophes not needed however. Much thanks!